# Date format from rrule in Calendar

Tags: android, calendar

I read out a recurring Calendar event. In this event there is a rrule (CalendarContract.Events.RRULE) which describes the recurring event. In it can be an "until" date which looks like the code snippset below. An example rrule could be: 
FREQ=WEEKLY;UNTIL=20121115T180000Z;BYDAY=MO,TU,WE,TH,FR
My question is about the date format. I don't know what "T" and "Z" means. Is it something with timezone?

```
String untilDate = "20121115T180000Z"

SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss'Z'");         
date = format.parse(untilDate);
```

EDIT:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmssZ");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The T and Z are literal letters, meaning there must be an actual T and Z in those respective positions.

In the date string, the T indicates that time follows (as opposed to date) and the Z indicates Zulu, or UTC (GMT) time.

Comment: Thanks a lot, then the EDIT in my Question would be correct? I used following docs: [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: No, in your edit, the Z looks for a time zone in the format of -0800 while your input string has an actual Z.  If your input will always have a Z, then just match it as you did before the edit and set the time zone of `format` to UTC.